# How to get value of string type

Tags: typescript

I want to create an object type that has the key of the value assigned to `type Test`.

Is there an option to get it better than using `[breakpoint in Test]`?

`[breakpoint in Test]` suggests that we want to iterate through multiple values.

```js
type Test = "s";

type TestObject = { [breakpoint in Test]: number; } // Returns { "s": number }
```

Comment: What "better" way do you have in mind? `Test` is a union, `TestObject` is a mapped type. `in` in the mapped type does not "suggest" iteration, it tells the compiler that keys of the object are of type `Test` which *happens* to have one member only.

Comment: You might write `Record<Test,number>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic type using a string variable as a property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330553/dynamic-type-using-a-string-variable-as-a-property-name)